# Aptana Studio not working on Maverick OSX

Tags: macos, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying running `Aptana Studio` on my Mac, but from some week I have this error message:

> The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Someone know how to fix it? Reinstalling `Aptana` did not resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=it_IT

Java 6 is necessary for Aptana 3